# Issue with subprocess.check_output printing stderr, looking to implement error checking

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to beautify the output of different system commands, but since I am using a non Redhat based OS my program snags executing the rpm feature. Could someone give a nudge in the right direction, I would like to make this more Pythonic and implement error checking against the rpm function if not a RH based OS.

```
def kernVer(kern1, kern2, kern3, kern4):
    if subprocess.check_output(["uname", "-a"]).decode('ascii').strip():
        print ('\x1b[6;30;42m' + '[✔] %s [✔]' % (kern1) + '\x1b[0m')
    if subprocess.check_output(["uname", "-mrs"]).decode('ascii').strip():
        print ('\x1b[6;30;42m' + '[✔] %s [✔]' % (kern2) + '\x1b[0m')
    if subprocess.check_output(["cat", "/proc/version"]).decode('ascii').strip():
        print ('\x1b[6;30;42m' + '[✔] %s' % (kern3) + '\x1b[0m')
    if subprocess.check_output(["rpm", "-q","kernel"]).decode('ascii').strip():
        print ('\x1b[6;30;42m' + '[✔] %s [✔]' % (kern4) + '\x1b[0m')
    else:
        print ('\x1b[1;32;41m' + '[✘] Unable To Obtain Kernel Version! [✘]' + '\x1b[0m')
        return
```

traceback from Atto Allas’s code:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Kern_Func_2.py", line 40, in <module>
    main()
  File "Kern_Func_2.py", line 35, in main
    kernel_info = get_kern_info()
  File "Kern_Func_2.py", line 20, in get_kern_info
    return_val = subprocess.check_output(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 316, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 383, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1289, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cat /proc/version'
```

I have also included an image of what is currently working in my program and to better illustrate desire results, including the kernels. I hope this better helps illustrate the dilemma.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, using a specific `try:` and `except:` is the most 'pythonic' way to do it. See the following example:

Replace:

```
if subprocess.check_output(["rpm", "-q","kernel"]).decode('ascii').strip():
    print ('\x1b[6;30;42m' + '[✔] %s [✔]' % (kern4) + '\x1b[0m')
else:
    print ('\x1b[1;32;41m' + '[✘] Unable To Obtain Kernel Version! [✘]' + '\x1b[0m')
    return
```

With:

```
try:
    subprocess.check_output(["rpm", "-q","kernel"]).decode('ascii').strip()
    print('\x1b[6;30;42m' + '[✔] %s [✔]' % (kern4) + '\x1b[0m')
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    print('\x1b[1;32;41m' + '[✘] Unable To Obtain Kernel Version! [✘]' + '\x1b[0m')
    return
```

or alternatively,

```
popen_check = subprocess.Popen(["rpm", "-q","kernel"])
popen_check.communicate()

if popen_check.returncode == 127: #127 is the command not found code
    print('\x1b[1;32;41m' + '[✘] Unable To Obtain Kernel Version! [✘]' + '\x1b[0m')
else:
    print('\x1b[6;30;42m' + '[✔] %s [✔]' % (kern4) + '\x1b[0m')
```

Note: I do not think your code will work, but this is how you *would* write your code, if it were correct. Also, I cannot write this code for you, because I don't actually know what you are trying to achieve.

An example of what your code *might* look like is this:

```
import subprocess

def get_kern_info():
    command_lists = [["uname", "-a"], ["uname", "-mrs"], ["cat /proc/version"], ["rpm", "-q","kernel"]]
    # cat is only one command because on some implementations, it breaks if the filepath is not directly in the same string as cat

    return_values = []

    for command in command_lists:
        try:
            return_val = subprocess.check_output(command)
            formatted_val = return_val.decode('ascii').strip()

            if formatted_val != '':
                return_values.append(formatted_val)
            else:
                return_values.append(str(command)+’ outputted nothing!’)

        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            return_values.append(str(command)+’ could not be called!’)
            continue

    return return_values

def main():
    kernel_info = get_kern_info()

    print("The data I got was: \n" + '\n'.join(kernel_info))

main()
```

Sample output from Windows bash terminal:

[image: Windows bash output]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Atto Allas, I appreciate the help, but like you mentioned I believe my approach is flawed and I am still unable to get the desired results. I am attempting to use the subprocess call to check the kernel version, if present and output it with print using hex to color code version(s) found, but since I am using a debian based OS at the moment, it will obviously error out on the rpm request. I was hoping to make it a universal script, by skipping kernels not present on the machine and reporting only versions found. Also, I thought calling it through a class would be best to keep it tidy

Comment: @th0r Just checking, do you want the function to output ALL of the data it can find (i.e. if it's a standard debian system, it would print 3 things) or just the first one it can find?

Comment: I would like it to print ALL output it can find, yes. So, as you stated Debian based OS would find the first three, 'uname -a', 'uname -mrs', 'cat /proc/version' and skip RPM if not found on the system. Trying to make the script universal as possible, as I add upon it. Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: @th0r Updated my answer. I hope it helps (I have not been able to thoroughly test it as at the moment I am on my Windows partition)

Comment: I really appreciate the help, but the code executes(no errors), but returns no output. I will tinker with the previous examples and the latest provided example and hopefully figure it out or just take out the rpm call. Thanks again for taking time to help.

Comment: @th0r Are you sure you called the `main()` function? The code I had before just included the functions and did not run any of them. Make sure that you add `main()` to the bottom of your python file.

Comment: Yes, it produced multiple errors. No worries, I don't even run RH so, I'll just remove that feature until my python skills catch up with my ambitions. The only goal was to better understand python and write a python code to do basic Linux checking for readable config files, perms and just trivial Linux hardening features for a security type checklist while implementing a new server. It was intended to help remind me of the, 'gotchas' and one off's why deploying a new server.

Comment: @th0r Can you tell me what the errors were? It would both help me learn and I might be able to fix them.

Comment: My apologies, but this is my first post ever on Stack. Is there a correct protocol on listing a list of errors beyond the 'Add Comment' buffer

Comment: @th0r it would be a bit painful in a comment, so I suggest you edit your question saying “traceback from Atto Allas’s code:” and then pasting the full traceback (formatted as code please!)

Comment: Thank you, I have provided the traceback and an image to hopefully better illustrate what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: @th0r Ah, I think I know what’s wrong. Try (in the command_lists variable)  replacing [‘cat /proc/version’] with [‘cat’, ‘/proc/version’]

Comment: @th0r I updated my answer to suit your needs. It will now display intelligible output when nothing could be found for that command, and you can check that to have your ticks and crosses.

Comment: Sadly, no luck! I truly appreciate all your time on this and don't want to take anymore time out of your weekend, but I'll just remove rpm from the original working script until I better understanding of the language to loop back around and hopefully resolve at a later time. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: with some minor modification I was able to get your script to run, but it still gets hung up on the ["rpm", "-q","kernel"]. If I remove the rpm request it runs beautifully on Ubuntu, Debian, but I would still love to have the feature available to run across multiple platforms.